# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers') at eval Next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, header

I am having this error in next js

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers')
> at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:254:61)

A sample of code snippet:

```
  newUser
    .save()
    .then(() =>
      NextResponse.json({ msg: "Successfuly created new User: " + newUser ,status:200})
    )
    .catch((err: string) =>{
    NextResponse.json({ error: "Error on '/api/register': " + err ,status:400})
    }
    );
```

Tried multiple approach like importing `NextApiRequest` and `NextApiResponse` and using it.
It has no status and JSON properties in it basically it is giving types error property does not exist  in `NextApiResponse`.
So I am using `NextResponse` directly still getting this error.

Answer (score 37):

I think you have to `return` the `NextResponse.json`.

That is what could be causing that error.

Comment: from a named route method (REST API) response should be explicitly returned from every path.

Answer (score 9):

it just happened to me and I found the answer in a [github issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/50679#issuecomment-1573705463) that worked for me. Just add a return statement on each case

```js
 newUser
    .save()
    .then(() =>
      return NextResponse.json({ msg: "Successfuly created new User: " + newUser ,status:200})
    )
    .catch((err: string) =>{
      return NextResponse.json({ error: "Error on '/api/register': " + err ,status:400})
    }
    );
```